# Flutter&Firebase: How to generate incremented numeric IDs for users?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to generates incremented numeric Ids and save it in firestore
I have some ideas for instance:

- Using transactions method to read integer number and store it for
  user and increment it.
- by create chain of documents with incremented Ids. And search for
  unused document using where at boolean field "used_num"=false.

Which is the best ?

Answer (score 0):

The second option isn't safe at all if you have multiple clients trying to each add a new number to the chain.  They could end up colliding and trying to write two documents with the same number.

The first option is at least safe.  But it's best not to have incremented numeric IDs at all if you can avoid it. That sort of scheme will cause issues with Firestore as the system scales up.